# insert composite type array gives error postgresql 9.4--

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
CREATE TABLE people(   
name_ varchar(50) NOT NULL,
count int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)

CREATE TABLE person_added(
date_ date NOT NULL,
all_people_ people[],
all_people_count int NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE all_people_array_table(
id SERIAL,
people_array person_added[]
)

INSERT INTO all_people_array_table(people_array) (SELECT ARRAY[CURRENT_DATE,  ARRAY[('Jack',3)::people,  ('John',6)::people], 1000]   )
```

I get this error;

ERROR:  ARRAY types date and emotions[] cannot be matched

What is the correct insert statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
insert into all_people_array_table(people_array)
select array[
    (current_date,
     array[
        ('Jack',3)::people,
        ('John',6)::people
     ], 1)::person_added
];
```

Comment: how can i insert into people_array column, another people[] element. How can i populate this array like  ('Jack',3),  ('John',8), ('Chris', 5) etc...with the same current_date value being inside array?

Comment: `update all_people_array_table set people_array[1].all_people_ = array_append(people_array[1].all_people_, ('Chris', 5)::people ) where id = 1;`

Comment: but I have to say this is not a true relational way to store your data. I suggest you to rethink your database structure.

Comment: great again thanks:)) and i need to do this way unfortunately...but anyways thanks for the tip.

Comment: last question:)...how can i select  people[] array in all_people_ column  , according to date in person_add table type(which is added by current_date)?